# Shell command to grep value for a key from a file

Tags: shell

content of formfile:

```
FORM_NAME ?= kindergarten
```

below command works to print the word "kindergarten"

```
grep -Po "(?<=^FORM_NAME \?\= ).*" formfile
#prints "kindergarten"
```

How to make it work by ignoring the spaces before and after "?=" ?

it should work for formfile with content:

```
FORM_NAME?=kindergarten
```

and

```
FORM_NAME   ?=   kindergarten
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -Po 'FORM_NAME\s*\?=\s*\K.*'
```

the above line would help you:

```
kent$  echo "FORM_NAME ?= kindergarten"|grep -Po 'FORM_NAME\s*\?=\s*\K.*'
kindergarten
```

Here the `\K` was used for the look-behind with dynamic length.